# Is there a quick solution to query a Lucene index from Node.js?

Tags: indexing, lucene, solr, node.js

I'm developing a server with node.js and would like to re-use the index files I generated with Lucene. Do you guys know a quick way to query this index from node.js?

Comment: there is a node-solr module https://github.com/gsf/node-solr

Comment: @generalhenry you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a node-solr module github.com/gsf/node-solr

Answer (score 0):

The module that has been mentioned previously as an answer to this question points to the library named node-solr which seems to be out of date and no longer maintained [according to the author](https://github.com/gsf/node-solr).

However, there is a library named [solr-node-client](https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client) that is [well documented](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/) and available for download via e.g npm.